# i have a access database i am using a update and join

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database and I am using this SQL to update my product table after I use the product from my order.

Is there a way to have it check to see if I already hit the update button that updates it so I do not remove it twice form my stock.

```
UPDATE ProductT 
INNER JOIN MaterialT ON MaterialT.ProductID = ProductT.ProductID 
SET ProductT.Stock = ProductT.Stock - MaterialT.Quantity
WHERE MaterialT.WorkOrderID = [OrderID];
```

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. You could try another query to check it and only return after that, or disable the button in your HTML or whatever frontend when submitting the query. There is too little context to your situation that it is _unclear what you are asking_

Comment: you can make trigger after updating record delete record from your stock, but that is wont be best scenario for what I think your are doing ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your frontend is a form in MS Access (since you are only using the `ms-access` tag), a simple solution could be to set the `Enabled` property of the button to `False` as the first operation of the On Click event, and issue a call to `DoEvents` to immediately update the display.

However, rather than subtracting a stock quantity from your `ProductT` table, a better practice would be to maintain a **Stock Transaction** table, and insert a record into such table corresponding to the allocation of stock of your material to your product.

This approach has several advantages, for example:

- You have a record of the stock that was allocated to each product, and hence an audit trail.
- You can check the Stock Transaction table for existing records corresponding to your stock movement before inserting a new record, avoiding the circumstance that you are currently trying to solve.
- The current stock of each material and the quantity of stock allocated to each product may be derived from your stock transaction table, either directly, or for stock checking purposes.